# Custom Page inside SharePoint 2010

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, publishing-page

i am building a .aspx Terms & condition page for my Intranet  with Save & Cancel buttons:

When we click on Save the user save inside a list as he agree on the terms & Condition content & the cancel button redirect to another site if they not agree on the content!

But i need your suggestion on below issue:

1 - How i can Hide the Terms & Condition page for the user that was agree on the content !

2-  How we set the page to popup on the welcome page site instead of a normal page

Any Help !

regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can use sharepoint dialog and cookies to this purpose.

Personally I would insert some javascript which would handle the check and popup in the masterpage or load it in a delegate control placed in the masterpage.

Javascript to load your .aspx:

```
var dialogOptions = {
        title: "Terms & Conditions",
        url: "/_layouts/PathToYourPage.aspx",
        allowMaximize: true,
        showMaximized: false,
        showClose: true,
        autoSize: true,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: function () { }
};    
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions);
```

You must then in your .aspx page set a cookie which you check if exists in the above javascript.

I can recommend the [jQuery.Cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for handling the cookie part.

Example:

```
var termsAcceptedCookie = jQuery.cookie("NameOfTheCookieHere"); // Could be a boolean.
if (!termsAcceptedCookie)
{
    var dialogOptions = {
        title: "Terms & Conditions",
        url: "/_layouts/PathToYourPage.aspx",
        allowMaximize: true,
        showMaximized: false,
        showClose: true,
        autoSize: true,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: function () { }
    };    
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions);
}
```

Comment: Would you help me more and give the steps :  1- to create the Delegation control & 2- where i can add the onload function to check and poup the content !  Thanks in advance